# Dr.Elephant eqivalent in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Dr.Elephant (https://github.com/linkedin/dr-elephant) is a very useful tool for performance monitoring and tuning for Hadoop and Spark jobs. Is there a similar tool for Flink?

Comment: Sadly, I don't know of any equivalent. Do you need something for Flink batch, or streaming, or both?

Comment: ideally we would like to have a performance tuning tool for both streaming and batch